# Mobile Web Site Templates

Tags: html, css, mobile, website-design

Is there any web site that you can recommend in which I can find premium (beautiful looking and professional) web site designs(themes) specific for mobile web sites? (paid or free)

Comment: Are you thinking about a theme for a particular blogging platform / CMS? There are premium mobile themes for Wordpress, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using WordPress, wptouch is awesome. See: https://www.bravenewcode.com/store/plugins/wptouch-pro/

Other than that, there are a lot of really good development frameworks emerging for mobile applications; two good ones are cssgrid (Fluid-width http://cssgrid.net/) and Less Framework (http://lessframework.com/).